# What "could hang together or one at a time" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Benjamin Franklin’s timely warning that the colonies **either could hang together or one at a time** ultimately translated itself into the brilliant outcome achieved by the revolutionary diplomats who seldom failed to take advantage of Europe’s distresses.

If hang = cut, what does this mean?
I'm confused about this phrase: either could hang together & hang one
at a time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the original quote:

> We must all hang together, or assuredly we shall all hang separately. -- Benjamin Franklin

*Hang* does not mean cut. It's a wordplay, and it means two different things. [Here's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang) the dictionary definition. The first meaning, in "*We must hang together*":

> Depend

The second meaning, in "*We shall all hang separately.*" is:

> To suspend by the neck until dead.

So his saying could be paraphrased as:

> We must depend on each other and support each other, or we will all be executed.

Comment: what does mean "at a time" ? does it refers to future?

Comment: @yorgun *One at a time* means individually.

Comment: 'United we stand, Divided we fall' is another popular way to state the same concept, without the clever wordplay with the dual meaning of 'hang.' Together means 'as a group' while 'at a time' means individually, or separately, or alone, or by himself.